# DIVs not abiding by CSS rules

Tags: css, html, width

I'm having some troubles with my HTML and CSS, in that the HTML on my siet isn't doing what I've put down in the CSS.
I'm trying to make a block of text have width: 50, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here's a code snippet:

```
<div id="welcome">
 <h2>Welcome!</h2>
 hello, this is some text.
<p>
 text before that text down there. v
<p>
 we have some text here.


<p><img src="images\halo.jpg" width="250" height= "250" alt="Master Chief" /><p>
</div>
```

This is from the site. I've put some rules down in the CSS to make this DIV, and other DIVs on seperate pages, have a width of 50%, but it just isn't working. Here's the CSS rule:

```
#welcome, #about, #contact {
 width: 50%;
 }
```

All my other CSS is working, and the HTML is correctly linked to the CSS. What am I doing wrong?
I've tried force-reloading, only having the rule for one DIV, and everything like that. If you can help me, thanks!

EDIT: Solved, thanks to ob. Cheers again.

-Tim

Comment: The sample code works fine for me. Check in a CSS debugger (such as Firebug or Safari's builtin web inspector) that the rule is being applied and look for other suspiciousness.

Comment: What are you seeing instead that says it's not working?

Comment: A sidenote, `img src="images\halo.jpg"1 should be `img src="images/halo.jpg"`. A forward slash. :P

Comment: Tim, what you mean with "it doesn't seem to be working"? ... I've tested your code and the width of the div is exactly the half of the web page's width!!!

Comment: If it's solved, please mark the answer that solved it for you as accepted (click the green checkmark on it)

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your page styles:

```
html, body, form { width:100% }
```

Comment: @Tim, cool that you got your problem solved. Do accept `ob`'s answer!

Answer (score 0):

The style definition seems OK.

Do you have any other style defined for div?

Is it working on some browsers and not on others?

You can easily diagnose the problem with web-developer tool or firebug.

Comment: I haven't tried it on other browsers, but I've just got Firebug, so I'll diagnose the problem now.
I don't have any other styles for div. There's nothing below it, either.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem often is the result of 50% width combined with 1px border. It's 50% + 1px, and therefore more than 50%.